# How to set image thumbnail for file stored on Google Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Using Google Drive API I can update any writeable file's attribute using `files.update()` method:

```
import datetime
data = {'modifiedTime': datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'}
drive_service.files().update(fileId=file_id, body=data, fields='id').execute()
```

Lets say I have a PNG image posted somewhere on a web: `'image':'http://pngimg.com/uploads/eagle/eagle_PNG1228.png'` or a png file that was saved on a local drive `"/Users/username/Downloads/my_image.png"`.

How to set a PNG file already posted on a web or a PNG file saved on a local drive as the thumbnail image for the file that is stored on Google Drive?

Here is what I tried so far.
With the `source.png` file saved on my local drive I went ahead and encoded it to `base64_encoded.png` file using this code (I am not sure if I did it correctly):

```
import base64

src = '/source.png'
dst = '/base64_encoded.png'

image = open(src, 'rb')
image_read = image.read()
encodestring = base64.encodestring(image_read)
image_result = open(dst, 'wb') 
image_result.write(encodestring)
```

I uploaded this `base64_encoded.png` file to Google Drive. I copied its URL address: `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1234567890abcdefgh`.

I set this URL address as a `thumbnail` metadata property of the file on Google Drive:

```
metadata =  { "contentHints": { 'thumbnail':{'image':'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1234567890abcdefgh'}}}
result = drive_service.files().update(fileId='abcdefgh1234567', body=metadata).execute()
```

But I am getting an error: `...returned "Invalid value for ByteString: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1234567">`

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this sample script?
`contentHints.thumbnail.image` is URL-safe Base64-encoded image. So an image data that you want to use as new thumbnail has to be converted to URL-safe Base64-encoded data. For this, it uses `base64.urlsafe_b64encode()` at Python.

And there are some limitations for updating thumbnail. Please check the detail information at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/file#upload_thumbnails.

I used zip file as a sample. Zip file doesn't have the thumbnail on Google Drive. When it confirms using `drive.files.get`, `hasThumbnail` is false. So this can be used. Although I used this script to Google Docs and images, the updated image was not reflected to them. This may touch to the limitations. When the thumbnail is given to the zip file, `hasThumbnail` becomes true. In my environment, at the first update, the update had sometimes been failed. But at that time, the second update had worked fine. I don't know about the reason. I'm sorry.

#### Sample script :

```
import base64  # Use this

with open("./sample.png", "rb") as f:
    metadata = {
        "contentHints": {
            "thumbnail": {
                "image": base64.urlsafe_b64encode(f.read()).decode('utf8'),
                "mimeType": "image/png",
            }
        }
    }
    res = drive_service.files().update(
        body=metadata,
        fileId="### file ID ###"
    ).execute()
    print(res)
```

#### Result :

[image]

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your url is not compliant to URL-safe Base64-encoded image (see [RFC 4648 section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5))

Try using any localhost then upload your image then use the path for the thumbnail. I've found a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/magikMaker/7bjaT/), where you can try your url if this is URL-safe Base64-encoded.

Tested your drive URL:

[image]

Tested **`www.localhost:8080/image/dog.png`** URL

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the fact the thumb URLwas not Base64 safe. I uploaded the thumb to another web server. I checked the new Thumb URL  with jsfiddle. It passed. But the command used to set Google Drive File's metadata fails `meta = { "contentHints": { 'thumbnail':{'image':'https://www.safeurl.com/encoded.png'}}}` fails.

Comment: `drive_service.files().update(fileId=file_id, body=meta).execute()` fails with the same error message: `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/....=json returned "Invalid value for ByteString..">`