# How to change the thumbnail of a google drive video?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

So for my class I have downloaded, and uploaded documentaries to gdrive I need to analyse. Though when I embed these google drive videos in notion.so (notion doesn't allow html type embeds, and only supports links without styling) the thumbnail will just be a random frame in the video. Is there any google apps script that can change the thumbnail to an image stored on my drive?

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749648/how-to-set-image-thumbnail-for-file-stored-on-google-drive), but it is of no luck to me. (I do know that it is not a google as)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: About `I am aware of this, but it is of no luck to me. (I do know that it is not a google as)`, I deeply apologize that my sample script was not useful for your situation. In this case, can I ask you about the detailed information of `it is of no luck to me`?

Comment: @Tanaike I used the script a while ago, and cannot remember what exactly happened, but it ran as normal, but the thumbnail didn't change. No error message or anything. Anyways I am not strong in Python, and would rather opt with gs (which is very similar to js which I am familiar with)

Comment: @DavidSalomon Sorry, I'm not sure what really to add. I as previously commented am not strong with python (probably as why the thumbnail didn't change), so I was looking for a google script alternative, where i wouldn't need to load up a python ide. Thanks for the advice nonetheless!

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, you want to change the thumbnail image of the video file which is in your Google Drive. You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script instead of python. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, exactly!

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested for changing the thumbnail of the video file using Drive API, the thumbnail of the video file couldn't be changed while the thumbnail of the ZIP file can be changed. It seems that this is the current specification. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike Ok, thankyou for your efforts. I just came across [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/file#:~:text=If%20Drive%20can%20generate%20a%20thumbnail%20from%20the%20file%2C%20then%20it%20will%20use%20the%20generated%20one%20and%20ignore%20any%20you%20may%20have%20uploaded.%20If%20it%20can%27t%20generate%20a%20thumbnail%2C%20it%20will%20always%20use%20yours%20if%20you%20provided%20one.) in the drive api documentations, so I think it will be entirely impossible for now.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the current stage, it seems that your goal cannot be directly achieved using Drive API. So can you post it as an answer? By this, I think that it will be useful for other users.

Comment: @Tanaike Though by any chance is there a way to add your own thumbnail to a file without a thumbnail already provided by google (like in your previous post, you changed the thumbnail for a zip), through a google apps script?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question.

Comment: @Tanaike No problem, I was just asking if it were possible to change lets say the thumbnail of a zip file using a google script. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45749648/17682002), but with a GS.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, it's yes.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you very much for all your help! And sorry to be a bother but how would you go about doing that?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Do you want the sample script for changing the thumbnail of the file (a ZIP file) using Google Apps Script? If my understanding is correct, can you update your question?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes. I will just answer this question, and open up a new one, as to keep the answer for video thumbnails here.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your new question, I would like to answer it.

Comment: @Tanaike Thankyou very much, I have just posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In short,

No. At this moment in time the google drive api does not allow changing thumbnails of files, in which google drive provides its own thumbnail.

> "If Drive can generate a thumbnail from the file, then it will use the generated one and ignore any you may have uploaded. If it can't generate a thumbnail, it will always use yours if you provided one." - [Google Drive for Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/file#uploading_thumbnails)