# How to change the thumbnail of a google drive .zip file?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45768378/17682002) guide to change the thumbnail of a .zip file. Though, I am not strong in python, and would prefer a google scripts alternative. Is this possible?

Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to change the thumbnail of a ZIP file using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set the file IDs of ZIP file and the image file you want to use as the new thumbnail image.

```
function myFunction() {
  const zipFileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of zip file.
  const imageFileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of the image file.

  const metadata = {
    thumbnail: {
      image: Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(DriveApp.getFileById(imageFileId).getBlob().getBytes()),
      mimeType: "image/png",
    }
  };
  Drive.Files.update(metadata, zipFileId); // or const res = Drive.Files.patch(metadata, zipFileId);
}
```

#### Note:

- About the limitation of the thumbnail, please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45768378/7108653).
- When you want to use the downloaded image as the thumbnail, please modify `image: Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(DriveApp.getFileById(imageFileId).getBlob().getBytes()),` as follows.

  ```
    image: Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(UrlFetchApp.fetch("URL").getContent()),
  ```
- In the current stage, Drive API of Advanced Google services is the version 2. By this, the request body is different from Drive API v3. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update)